# Is it possible to manage one domain in Route53 from 2 AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have production and development accounts on AWS. I have a domain `acmeinc.com` and would like to create Route53 records in *both* accounts:

- `app.prod.acmeinc.com` (production)
- `app.dev.acmeinc.com` (development)

It seems that I need a public hosted zone in each account for `acmeinc.com`.

Can AWS support this? If not, is there a work-around?

---

Note: I am using Terraform on each account separately (one TF state for each account), hence need to manage one domain from two accounts.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called DNS delegation, which is quite possible with route 53.
First, create a hosted zone in each account `prod.acmeinc.com`/`dev.acmeinc.com`:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "prod-acmeinc-subdomain" {
  name = "prod.acmeinc.com"
}
```

Next, create a NS record in each zone:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "nameservers" {
  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = aws_route53_zone.prod-acmeinc-subdomain.name
  ttl             = 3600
  type            = "NS"
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.prod-acmeinc-subdomai.zone_id

  records = aws_route53_zone.prod-acmeinc-subdomain.name_servers
}
output "prod-acmeinc-zone-ns" {
  value = aws_route53_zone.prod-acmeinc-subdomain.name_servers
}
```

Output the NS record, and you need to add it to the DNS records of acmeinc.com. , with type `NS` and record name `prod.acmeinc.com`. If you also host acemin.com in Route53 you can also use terraform as well.

Now `prod.aceminc.com` points to your prod environment, and `dev.aceminc.com` to your dev environment, and you can add any related dns entries in the created zones.

If `aceminc.com` is not hosted anywhere, you can use the production account to host the entire zone there, and only delegate the development environment the same way as described above.